# Managed .Net C++/CLI - Structures

Tags: .net, structure

I have defined the following structure below.

```
typedef union
{
    struct
    {
        unsigned command:15;
        unsigned acknowledge:1;
    };
    struct
    {
        unsigned short uicommand;
    };
    struct
    {
        Byte command_bytes[2];
    };
}TCOMMAND;
```

After then declaring a variable of type TCOMMAND E.G

```
TCOMMAND mycommand
int x=sizeof(mycommand)
```

The value of x is 4 bytes instead of 2.
Enlightenment on the problem will be appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In C/C++ `unsigned` means `unsigned int` and even if you don't assign all of the bits of a bit field, the compiler will still size your structure to the data type specified.

So assuming a 32 bit `int` (which is the default in Visual C++) the first structure of your union is the same as:

```
struct
{
    unsigned int command:15;
    unsigned int acknowledge:1;
    unsigned int __unused:16;
};
```

Which is four bytes.  Use an `unsigned short`  in your first structure if you want it to be only two bytes:

```
struct
{
    unsigned short command:15;
    unsigned short acknowledge:1;
};
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe it's because **unsigned int** has 4-byte alignment. If you use **unsigned short** for the **command** and **acknowledge** members, the structure will be 2 bytes large.

Answer (score 2):

This is caused by the compiler options. Newer compilers make memory alignments. This also affects the size of your unions/structures. There are some pragma solutions like `#pragma pack`. see and try the code below.

```
#pragma pack(push, 1)
typedef union
{
    struct
    {
        unsigned command:15;
        unsigned acknowledge:1;
    };
    struct
    {
        unsigned short uicommand;
    };
    struct
    {
        Byte command_bytes[2];
    };
}TCOMMAND;
#pragma pack(pop)
```

`push, 1` tells compiler to align block to 1 byte. this was the default value for older compilers but probably changed with the newer ones.

Comment: Not quite.. Still came out as 4 bytes.. That #pragma pack really didn't pack at all.. Actually it did nothing visible.Declaring the first part of the structure as unsigned short worked though..
Thanks.

Comment: Then my answer was wrong for this case. But still keep in mind that compilers can cause different sizing issues as optimizations and my answer is correct for other scenarios.

Comment: Actually your answer did help. I used TCOMMAND in another structure I created and without the #pragma pack statement wrapped around both structures, they were misaligned. Your answer is correct!!!. I'm going to wrap all of my stuctures around this now!!!
Thanks.
Peter

Comment: I'm glad i could help. I had similar problems when trying to use an old pci camera card SDK from C++/CLI which was written in VC++ 6.0.